# c# code to connect to SQL server which is on different machine

Tags: c#, sql, .net, string, connection

I have created c#.net application with its setup. the setup installs app files and execute database script file. it work proper if SQL server is located on local machine. but when SQL server is located on different machine but in same domain at that time setup fails and database file not get executed. and my application failed to create database.

I need help in this please .....

I used connection string as follows.

```
connsctionString = "Data Source=filesvr;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master;";
```

after this my code is

```
con = new SqlConnection(connsctionString);
con.Open();
```

when this `con.Open()` line executes it gives error as

```
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

also please confirm is it necessary to provide user id and password in connection string if SQL is on different machine?

Comment: You wouldn't use integrated security on remote machines, set up a username and password and this should solve things.

Comment: Put a try catch to better understand the error

Answer (score 1):

i hope it is useful to u

```
    "Data Source=filesvr;database=master; UId=abc;pwd=xyz";

you can also use ipaddress in data source of the system in which u access sql database
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are trying to login from a different server, you cannot access the database server with `windows authentication`. You have to login with a username+password. Here is a sample which you can try.

```
connsctionString = "Data Source=Server_Name/IP; Initial Catalog=Your_Database;User Id=your_user_name/Id;Password=your_password;pooling='false'; Encrypt=False";
```

This is tested. Will work for sure. Let me know if it is helpful to you.